# What does triviality and non-triviality mean in field theory?

Tags: condensed-matter, field-theory, polymers

I am studying polymer physics and their basic field theoretical models which has connections to $\Phi ^{4}$ field theory. I frequently come in touch with statements about triviality and non-triviality of the theory with respect to the space dimension $d$. Can somebody explain what does it mean to talk about triviality and non-triviality of a theory?

Comment: [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_triviality) no good?

Comment: @CosmasZachos It did shed some light but I still have doubts in the present context. I don't have background in QFT. So please help me understand. If I am correct then triviality of a scalar field theory lies in it's correspondence with the Gaussian free field behavior. The fixed points of the RG equation for an interacting model (self-avoidance limit or the Quadratic Hamiltonian + the self energy term) derived as a result  of coupling constants attaining fully developed values dictates the Triviality or nontriviality as a function of Spatial dimension.

Comment: Rather this scholarpedia article turned out to be more illuminating: http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Triviality_of_four_dimensional_phi%5E4_theory_on_the_lattice